# Pulsar intro comando cmd o php

Tags: php, ubuntu, cmd, terminal

Estoy intentando ejecutar el comando ssh y he conseguido entrar sin poner la contraseña después ya que lo hago a través de PHP y e logrado introducirla en el mismo comando. El problema es que después tengo que pulsar la tecla intro y eso no consigo saltármelo o hacer que se pulse la tecla mediante un comando o algo. Gracias de antemano.

sshpass -p <<contraseña>> ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 admin@direccion_ip